# Change local windows user properties using C#

Tags: c#, windows, properties, accounts

I am looking for a simple method to modify a local user's properties in windows 7 using a simple c# application.

I am not familiar with many of the Windows system libraries and am looking to accomplish each of the following tasks:

1. Enable/Disable a local user account in windows.
2. Change the password of a local user account in windows.

Some example code and an simple explanation of what the code does would be very helpful.

#### Edit:

I will have administrative access to the machine when this program is going to be run.

Comment: Hmmm... Sounds malicious to me. I can't think of a reason you'd want to do this that isn't for doing something bad. And Win7 requires you be logged in as an administrative user to do either of these things.

Comment: This is not malicious, it is meant for a class project, I will have administrative access when this program is executed.

Comment: These settings can be modified via NetUserSetInfo and USER_INFO_1; not sure if there is a managed equivalent or not (probably is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access this will give you access to what you need.

```
DirectoryEntry localDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://"Environment.MachineName.ToString());
DirectoryEntries users = localDirectory.Children;
DirectoryEntry user = users.Find("userName");
```

Here is a link to the docs..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx

Comment: also more of an overview: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx

Comment: This was a great help, the following documentation was also useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180911%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have had a really great experience using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.  It lets you do all the stuff you want to do with accounts without needing to mess with magic strings.

System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx

The key entry point to look at is the [PrincipalContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) class.